# JavaScript promise won't resolve or reject, it just blocks for some reason

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-promise

I'm writing a node script, which is supposed to order images by a **score** value, calculated by a function called `getImageScore()`. This **score** takes quite some time to be calculated, therefore I created a promise (`promiseImageScore`) that would return the **score** value. After getting the promised value by the `promiseImageScore` promise, the program would log the name of the image and its **score**. Despite creating a promise for the **score** values, they still come back as `undefined`. I observed the promises would never finish, they just always remain in `pending` state. I tried tracing what's actually happening in the `getImageScore()` function, by logging some messages through the function and, as expected, those logs stop at some point, but I cannot get why this happens. Here is the full program:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const { resolve } = require('path');
const { reject } = require('q');
const { Console } = require('console');
const gm = require('gm').subClass({imageMagick: true});
const PNG = require("pngjs").PNG;
let pathToFolder = '/home/eugen/Pictures/wallpapers1';
let pathToImage = '';

let promiseImageScore = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  resolve(getImageScore());
});

function getImageScore() {
  console.log('entered this promise....');
  let img = gm(pathToImage);
  // Get the PNG buffer
  img.toBuffer("PNG", (err, buff) => {
    if (err) return new Error(err);
    console.log('got buffer...');
    // Get the image size
    img.size((err, size) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return new Error(err);
      }
      console.log('got image size...');
      // Parse the PNG buffer
      let str = new PNG();
      str.end(buff);

      // After it's parsed...
      str.on("parsed", buffer => {
        // Get the pixels from the image
        let idx, score = 0, rgb = {r: 0, g: 0, b: 0};

        for (let y = 0; y < size.height; y++)
          for (let x = 0; x < size.width; x++) {
            idx = (size.width * y + x) << 2;
            rgb.r = buffer[idx];
            rgb.g = buffer[idx + 1];
            rgb.b = buffer[idx + 2];
            score += (rgb.r + rgb.g + rgb.b) / 765;
          }
          console.log('one promised finished...');
          return score / (size.height * size.width);
      });
      str.on("error", e => {
        return new Error(e);
      });
    });
  });
}

// see which images are to be found in the specificd directory
fs.readdir(pathToFolder, function (err, files) {
    if (err) return console.log('Unable to scan directory: ' + err);
    console.log('files in directory:\n');
    files.forEach(function (file) {
        pathToImage = pathToFolder + '/' + file;
        //showImageScore();
        promiseImageScore
        .then(imageScore => {
          console.log(file + ' has a score of ' + imageScore);
        })
        .catch(e => {
          throw e;
        })
    });
});
```

Here is the output of the code:

```
entered this promise....
files in directory:

Boats_Thailand_Sea_Crag_Nature_8000x5224.jpg has a score of undefined
Wallpaper_8K_0_7680x4320.jpg has a score of undefined
Water_mountains_landscapes_nature_snow_valley_rocks_switzerland_rivers_3840x2400.jpg has a score of undefined
Waterfalls_USA_Crag_Trees_Hocking_Hills_State_Park_Ohio_Nature_10929x5553.jpg has a score of undefined
cats_blue_eyes_animals_pets_4288x2848.jpg has a score of undefined
cats_blue_eyes_animals_pets_4288x2848.png has a score of undefined
city_night_panorama_117682_3840x2160.jpg has a score of undefined
starry_sky_tree_night_sky_119989_1920x1080.jpg has a score of undefined
got buffer...
```

After the `got buffer...` log, the program keeps running, never stopping, apparently doing nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not working with promises correctly. You need to make several changes:

1. Pass the `resolve` and `reject` to `getImageScore`:

```js
const promiseImageScore = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  // You need to pass resolve and reject to getImageScore
  getImageScore(resolve, reject);
});
```

2. Use `resolve` and `reject` in `getImageScore`:

```js
// For example
img.toBuffer("PNG", (err, buff) => {
  // If you get an error you need to call reject and return from the function
  // You will need to do the same for img.size((err, size) => {})
  // and for str.on("error", e => {})
  if (err) return reject(err);

  // Then when you have your result and there were no errors,
  // you will need to call resolve with the result
  resolve(score / (size.height * size.width));
});
```